# Fastest way to check if comma separated string contains at least 1 valid integer?

Tags: java, string, performance

I have a String with comma separated positive integers, for example:

```
1,34,433,12
```

What is the fastest way to determine if the string contains at least 1 integer?

Right now I `split(",")`, loop over the resulting `String[]` and try to parse each element as an int.

This works in order to get a `List<Integer>` of the String but I want the fastest way possible to determine if the String is valid for this.

`1a,2b,13` is acceptable. `1a,2b,13c` is not acceptable.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to check that the string contains at least one digit, as the title and beginning of the question says, or do you want to check that the string can be split on commas to produce a list of integers, as suggested by the last part of the question?

Comment: @JBNizet: I want to check if the comma separated list contains at least 1 valid number

Comment: Why don't you write **that** int he question then?

Comment: @JBNizet: I have updated OP.

Comment: Are numbers always integers?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk:Yes and in a small range. Biggest one is 500

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds pretty efficient as it is. Will solve in 1 to n iterations. Not sure what you could possibly do to make it faster.

Comment: @Compass:My approach depends on an exception thrown. AFAIK that is pretty inefficient

Comment: Are numbers always not negative?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk:Always positive

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
public static boolean containsInt(String string) {
    boolean onlyDigits = true;
    boolean atLeastOneDigit = false;
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (c == ',') {
            if (atLeastOneDigit && onlyDigits) {
                return true;
            }
            onlyDigits = true;
            atLeastOneDigit = false;
            continue;
        }
        boolean isDigit = c >= '0' && c <= '9';
        onlyDigits &= isDigit;
        atLeastOneDigit |= isDigit;
    }
    return atLeastOneDigit && onlyDigits;
}
```

Now, a more readable version using Guava:

```
public static boolean containsInt(String text) {
    for (String s : Splitter.on(',').split(text) {
        if (Ints.tryParse(s) != null)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This `"1a,2b,13"` is acceptable. This `"1a,2b,13c"` is not acceptable

Comment: @SamiKorhonen It doesn't have to, numbers are always positive referring to OP's comment under the question.

Comment: Using `string.charAt()` directly rather than `toCharArray()` must be better.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested solutions proposed by Jim (OP), Jean and Andreas (with compiling the pattern only once out of the loop).

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/555acba98e6982a02f71) of test. I used [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

### Results

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testJim      thrpt   20    32.895 ±  0.708  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testJean     thrpt   20  2806.981 ± 31.295  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testAndreas  thrpt   20    41.789 ±  6.033  ops/s
```

Jean's solution is definitely the fastest. I cannot think of anything faster in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since your String only needs to contain at least a single number, why not iterate over it and check if there is at least one digit (0-9), and whether there are any non number/comma symbols in there?

Comment: You may not even need to iterate over it.  You could just write a loop that checks "instr" for each of the digits.

Comment: @Jim: In that case you may want to edit your original post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a job for regular expressions.

About 90% of the time when you see `.toCharArray()` someone is reinventing regular expressions. Don't reinvent the wheel!

```
public class Jim {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    final String[] strings = new String[]{
        //valid
        "1,34,433,12",
        "12,safdg,sfdg",
        "asfd,asdf,12",
        "asfd,10,jrtj",
        "12356",
        ",12356,",
        //invalid
        "asdf",
        "1a,2b,13c",
        ",asdf,",
        ",,,",
        "",
    };
    for (String s : strings) {
      System.out.println(String.format("data: [%s], outcome: [%s]", s, hasNumericField(s)));
    }
  }
  
  //\A matches the start of the input, thus
  //(\A|,) matches the start of the input or a comma, thus 
  //(\z|,) works the same way but with the end of the input.
  //\d+ matches one or more digits.
  private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\A|,)\\d+(\\z|,)");
  
  private static boolean hasNumericField(final String commaSeparatedData) {
    return pat.matcher(commaSeparatedData).find();
  }
  
}
```

One of the joys of regular expressions is that it adapts well to changes in input. You just change the expression. If you hand code something you'll likely need to rework -> test -> debug it if the inputs change.

Comment: When it comes to performance (and OP asks specifically for that) regular expressions will not be the fastest solution - please refer to my [benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875133/fastest-way-to-check-if-comma-separated-string-contains-at-least-1-valid-integer/32875159#answer-32876058).

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I agree 100%, OP asked for speed and regex will not be the fastest. However, it may be the cleanest and most maintainable (though Jean's second solution looks pretty darn good).